# Inaccessible host: aws error on cdk deploy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

hi I am trying to run command `cdk deploy my-app` and getting this error .  it was working fine but suddenly stopped  working.

this is exact error
**Inaccessible host: `cloudformation.us-west-2.api.aws' at port` undefined'. This service may not be available in the `us-west-2' region.: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cloudformation.us-west-2.api.aws**

my cdk version is **cdk --version =  2.0.0**

Comment: Start by updating the CDK cli.

Comment: Are you behind any proxy server?

Comment: @Myz not sure as getting this internet from local ISP . is this the reason ?

Comment: @gshpychka updating cdk is now 2.1.5 bus still issue same

Comment: This is an issue with your internet connection.

Comment: @gshpychka I have only this internet in my hostel] premises is there any work round or any thing I can do rn ?

Answer (score 0):

Same issues on me.

I solved the problem fixing my environment to:

```
  env: { account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION }
```

I think it is the bug in the latest CDK when using region code as string. I found same issues on examples using region code as string.